# How to load Runtime environmental variables in NextJS application

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, getserversideprops

I am deploying a NextJS app in various K8 environments, each passing it's own variables. I can pass them in and get them with `getServerSideProps()`, but as this function works on page components (or at least that's what the docs say), I have to add them in every single page through which my users can "enter" the application. This becomes error prone.

What I would like, ideally, is to be able to have a `getServerSideProps()` on the `_app.tsx`, which I cannot.

What is the best alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-initial-props) seems what you want.

```js
App.getInitialProps = async ({  ctx }: AppContext) => {
  const something = await getData();

  return { pageProps: { something } }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).